# how to show $\frac{x+x^2+\dots+x^m}{1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n}$ decreases in $x$ for $x\geq1$, where m,n are integers and 0<m<n?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to show $\frac{x+x^2+\dots+x^m}{1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n}$ decreases in $x$ for $x\geq 1$, assuming that $m,n$ are integers and $0<m<n$.

It seems an easy question, but I can't prove it.  Can anyone give a hint?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you try showing its derivative is negative?

Comment: Both numerator and denominator are geometric series. Now taking derivatives will be easy.